# How do you view medals in Halo 5's carnage report?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I can see commendations and lifetime medals earned but how do I view medals in a match's carnage report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/no-medals-in-the-post-carnage-report/1e759e0c-a6f9-4202-b59c-ba5f0f472d38/posts), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/3qjlks/why_cant_we_see_medals_at_end_of_game/) and a couple of other Reddit and Halo Waypoint posts you can't see the medals in the post-game carnage report (as of now). 343 might decide to add it later but currently viewing medals post-game is not available.